# Not sure how to use this formula for auctions

Tags: auctions

In my textbook I was given this formula for auctions:

[image]

As far as I understand, $N$ is number of people who place bets, $P_{personal}$ means my subjective value of the current lot (it's also assumed that it's the highest subjective value among people placing their bets), $P_{max1}$ is maximum price (not sure what it means).

My textbook seems to imply, that in order to avoid "Winner's curse" our bet must be equal to $P_{max2}$ because it reflects the true value of a traded lot. Otherwise, after such victories we will go broke.

In order to calculate $P_{max2}$ we use following formula:
[image]

My difficulties are with formula for $P_{max1}$.

1.For what kinds of auctions can I use this formula?

2.What is the difference between $P_{personal}$ and $P_{max1}$?

3.Why is $P_{max2}$ supposed to be the real value of the traded lot?

4.What to do if I'm **not** sure that my subjective value of this lot is the highest among participants?

5.Let's suppose that I want to win the lot in order to resell it for higher price. On one hand, if I don't place high enough bet, then it will mean that I will win less frequently. And it can be painful because I can have fixed costs to be paid, no matter if I win or lose. On the other hand, by increasing my bet I decrease my profit margin. So it's unclear for me how to calculate my $P_{personal}$ in this case.

6.Please, give me the name of this formula, if it has name.

Comment: Since this is related to the [winner's curse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winner%27s_curse), the auction is probably a form of [common value auction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_value_auction). However, the information you provide does not seem sufficient to answer your questions. Try to re-read your textbook more carefully. It must have information about the context of the auction, its rules, etc. If not, you should look for a different text.

Comment: " If not, you should look for a different text.". Can you recommend any sources where I can find the same formula?

Comment: What's your level of study?

Comment: @herr-k Undergraduate

Comment: Consider the optional readings suggested in Phil Reny's [undergraduate auction theory course](https://15bdb8d0-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/philipjreny/econ-20800-course-outline.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7cqTVeyjyVra-9yLkfZ6M4y1IZJsJjtu_VvKc4qUlISSuZBJvXHHIBYzbO1OWX1-rLbn7DiQUnsBE8KBzl9c1aIt4P0KReEHTcslpFwtNoc7cOUpKR5YseeZM3Q6f4WwuGSj_4PtORKmCfdXq-Xbi68RJEj72-gGgkjg69dwsAjvalwQvlLXL4t3llegKqOKkVA9vXYmkxVMLFH-8XtBsCRIfznlnzdsKEA_vO8qymwzw3mvVcA%3D&attredirects=0).